# Sencha touch 2 - How to detect when a user navigates from one URL to another?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, window.onunload

I am developing a Sencha touch 2 app where I want to detect when the user navigates from one page to another. I want to call a function just like "onunload" in javascript. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the way you are implementing your navigation.

**1. NavigationView**

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View

The NavigationView is a card based layout where you can `pop` or `push` views.
There are events like `activeitemchange`, `pop`, `push` etc.

You can add these events as listener to your component

**Example:**
    listeners : {
        pop : function(cmp, view, eOpts) {

```
        ...

    }
}
```

**2. Container Navigation**

You can create a card based container and add/remove the views from this container.

There you are able to use the `activeitemchange`, `add` and `remove` event.

But in both cases its mostly the same. You have to set a listener with the event to the outer container (where your views are inside). There you can define your action for switches of views

Comment: I tried your answer. I am using Container navigation. I am able to detect only when a particular view changes (through "activeitemchange"). But I want to call a function when a particular view unloads.
Say it is a "signupview"- I dont want to call a function for switch of views rather I would like to do it for a specific view "unload". Is that possible?